# Axios interceptor override

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

We have react app and it implements **axios** interceptors, means if any network call responds **401** it redirect to **login** page. Next, we are using another react local library(lets say **authLib**) which is also implements same **axios** interceptors. So when network responds 401 error, both are executing(one for main app and another one for local library). How can we avoid to call once or override the axios interceptor.

```
var axiosObj = axios.create(); 
axiosObj.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {                               
return response;                                                                        
}, function (error) {                                                                  
if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
 logout();
return;  }                                                                         
return Promise.reject(error);});
```

Comment: can't you remove the redirect logic from axios-interceptor and let the other library do it

Comment: Avoid adding interceptors on the default `axios` instance. Instead, create new instances

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios interceptor intercepting all Axios requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672337/axios-interceptor-intercepting-all-axios-requests)